# Remote Updating of JAR file

Tags: java, jar

I have a JAR file of a project which im creating for a business. It will be places on their network drive and ran from there by several people throughout the company.

I will be leaving the business soon but would like the ability to remotely update the JAR file with small bugfixes if anything is reported.

Ideally its as simple as placing a new JAR in a folder on server and current JAR will check for update on launch and update if necessary. The same effect with an Android App or Firefox.

Whats the most common way of doing this?

Comment: Do you have SSH access?

Comment: No i just have a shared server with Namecheap now. Is SSH vital? I will just run an update maybe once a month to 1 Jar File. It says Limited SSH Access on Server Specs.

Comment: SSH would be pretty important. Especially if you're talking about doing this outside of their network so that any information sent would be encrypted. Ask if SSH is an option. Then there are plenty of ways to do this.

Comment: Its a lot of expense just to swap a JAR file. Probably better just emailing the file to an employee and asking them to swap it. The shared server is my own and i was gonna just use it to update. Any easy way of doing it without SSH?

Comment: The idea of how dropbox works would be perfect but the internal setup is probably wrong. This company has 100s of machines all connected to same network drive which will store the JAR file. Where would dropbox run from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are describing is a [JNLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start)
It is a file that points to a .jar on a server. When it is updated Java Web Start will download the latest .jar and run it.

Answer (score 1):

As @Dominick mentions, if you have SSH access, you could write a script to send the update via the uf option. See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html).

```
jar uf jar-file input-file(s)
```

---

**EDIT**

Would version control be an option for you? you could do the bug fixes on your local machine, push them to a repository the company has access to, then have them update the jar files whenever there's a new version.

Comment: Would anyone need knowledge of version control? The employees wouldn't know the first thing about version control. The JAR file would need to update like an android app. really simply.

Comment: I imagine they would, unless you could have a script running to compare the current version with the one at the repo. If the hashes didn't match, then pull the latest version. Not sure how well that would work if the current jar file was in use though. Good luck with it.